# Reasons for not using Thread.join()

Tags: java, multithreading

Lately, I have been told by Senior Developers not to use Thread.join() to wait for another Thread to finish. I've also seen several such questions on SO asking alternates to join.

In my research, I couldn't find anything wrong with join(). In fact it is widely used.

So I would like to know why not use join()? What is wrong with it? Does it promotes poor programming or architecture?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, if you need to wait for threads to complete. That's what it's for.

Comment: I suppose if your thread(s) never completes it will suspend (not lock) the main thread indefinitely, but that's not a problem with `join`, that's a problem with your program.

Comment: Ask the 'senior developers' what they're talking about. Maybe what they really mean is don't wait for other threads to finish at all. Who knows? Why are you asking here?

Comment: @EJP see the top answer: they use Executors.newFixedThreadPool everywhere. makes sense. the reason I ask here is because I wanted to do some research and be prepared by having some background info. doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: *they use Executors.newFixedThreadPool everywhere.* Tell them they are doing it wrong, usually you do not need a lot of thread pools to boot, esp. fixed ones.  `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` creates a pool w/ unbound queue and that can bite you so hard in production, it's difficult to imagine, as rule of the thumb, do not use unbound queues. If you start threads, `join` is a natural choice but starting threads usually involves infrastructural code.

Answer (score 34):

There's nothing wrong with `join()`. It is as good as it gets.

However, here's why you shouldn't architect your application to rely on joins. In Java, the primary abstraction for running tasks isn't Thread anymore. It is `Executor`. That is you wrap the concurrent tasks as `Callable` and simply submit it to an `Executor` without worrying about the execution details. This is how `Executor`s work. You `submit` or `execute` a `Callable` or `Runnable` respectively and no need to specify Thread.

> So I would like to know why not use join()?

Then here's your reason: Since you don't create or manipulate Threads in the Executor world, there's no point in using `join`. Almost every `join` could be replaced with something else (`Future.get`, `CountDownLatch`, `Locks`, etc.).

---

Note: I'm not saying that you don't need to manipulate Threads when using Executors. In some cases, it's better to create own Thread subclass and then have Executor use them via `ThreadFactory`.

Comment: *it's better to create own Thread subclass and then have Executor use them via ThreadFactory* what's the point of subclassing `java.lang.Thread`?

Answer (score 11):

There's nothing wrong with using Thread.join in general, however you need to be very careful and **know where the thread comes from**. If it comes from a **thread pool** - then you're in a trouble indeed, because such threads are running until the pool is terminated and shared between several workers.

Answer (score 2):

A [Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) framework was introduced in Java 7. Consider using it instead of Thread.join(). In general you should use classes from package java.util.concurrent.* where possible, minimizing usage of original synchronization techniques like synchronized blocks, wait/notify and join. java.util.concurrent gives much more flexibility.

Comment: *minimizing usage of original synchronization techniques like synchronized blocks, wait/notify*, sync blocks are just fine, esp. if you expected w/ lower contention. The sync block can be often a better choice than `ReentrantLock`, look at [CHMv8](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/ConcurrentHashMapV8.java?view=log) for instance. Doug Lea reverts back to regular sync. blocks

Answer (score 1):

IMO there is nothing wrong with join. You just need to take care to ensure that the thread you are waiting on terminates in all circumstances. Since if it does not then the execution may halt forever. 
So if you are making the main thread wait on some thread using join and the thread does not terminate it may cause your entire application to freeze.